"cuStreamSynchronize failed: an illegal memory access was encountered
When I run my tensorRT engine created from ONNX file of a single transformer layer, I faced an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ipa/seokwon/mywork/llm/myproject/execute_engine.py", line 212, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ipa/seokwon/mywork/llm/myproject/execute_engine.py", line 198, in main
    model(model_inputs)
  File "/home/ipa/seokwon/mywork/llm/myproject/execute_engine.py", line 147, in __call__
    self.stream.synchronize()
pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuStreamSynchronize failed: an illegal memory access was encountered

The error only occurs when I run the engine for large batch sizes or sequence lengths..
It works correctly for python execute_engine.py --model=JambaAttentionDecoderLayer-2-decoding.trt --batch=2 --seqlen=8192  but when I increase the batchsize to 4 as python execute_engine.py --model=JambaAttentionDecoderLayer-2-decoding.trt --batch=4 --seqlen=8192, it reports the above error.
The full code is as below:
from collections import OrderedDict,namedtuple
import tensorrt as trt 
import time
import numpy as np
import argparse

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit

import torch

class TRTModel:
    class HostDeviceMem(object):
        def __init__(self, host_mem, device_mem, dtype, shape = None):
            self.host = host_mem
            self.device = device_mem
            self.dtype = dtype
            self.shape = shape
    
    def __init__(self, engine_path):
        self.engine_path = engine_path
        self.logger = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.INFO)
        self.runtime = trt.Runtime(self.logger)
        self.engine = self.load_engine()
        print(f"Device memory of profile0 (bytes): {self.engine.get_device_memory_size_for_profile_v2(0)}")
        print(f"Device memory of profile1 (bytes): {self.engine.get_device_memory_size_for_profile_v2(1)}")
        print(f"Device memory size (bytes): {self.engine.device_memory_size_v2}")
        self.inputs, self.outputs, self.bindings, self.stream = self.allocate_buffers(self.engine)
        self.context = self.engine.create_execution_context()  

    def load_engine(self):
        with open(self.engine_path, 'rb') as f:
            engine = self.runtime.deserialize_cuda_engine(f.read())
        return engine

    def allocate_buffers(self, engine):
        '''
        Allocates all buffers required for an engine, i.e. host/device inputs/outputs.
        '''
        inputs = []
        outputs = []
        bindings = []
        stream = cuda.Stream()

        for i in range(engine.num_io_tensors):
            tensor_name = engine.get_tensor_name(i)
            shape = engine.get_tensor_profile_shape(name=tensor_name, profile_index=0)[2]
            size = trt.volume(shape) # [2]: max buffer allocation size
            dtype = trt.nptype(engine.get_tensor_dtype(tensor_name))

            print(f"Tensor name: {tensor_name}")
            print(f"Size: {size}, Shape: {shape}, Dtype: {dtype}")

            # Allocate host and device buffers
            host_mem = cuda.pagelocked_empty(size, dtype) #page-locked memory buffer (won't swapped to disk)
            device_mem = cuda.mem_alloc(host_mem.nbytes) # returns a device pointer

            # Append the device buffer to device bindings
            # When cast to int, it's a linear into the context's memory (like memory address).
            bindings.append(int(device_mem))

            # Append to the appropriate input/output list.
            if engine.get_tensor_mode(tensor_name) == trt.TensorIOMode.INPUT:
                inputs.append(self.HostDeviceMem(host_mem, device_mem, dtype, shape))
            else:
                pass

        return inputs, outputs, bindings, stream

    def __call__(self, model_inputs: list):
        # Set input shape based on input dimensions
        for i in range(self.engine.num_io_tensors):
            tensor_name = self.engine.get_tensor_name(i)
            if self.engine.get_tensor_mode(tensor_name) == trt.TensorIOMode.INPUT:
                # shape = self.engine.get_tensor_profile_shape(name=tensor_name, profile_index=0)[1]
                shape = model_inputs[i].shape
                print(f"Input shape [{tensor_name}]: {shape}")
                self.context.set_input_shape(tensor_name, shape)
            elif self.engine.get_tensor_mode(tensor_name) == trt.TensorIOMode.OUTPUT:
                shape = self.context.get_tensor_shape(tensor_name)
                # Reallocate output buffers with actual output tensor shape
                size = trt.volume(shape)
                dtype = trt.nptype(self.engine.get_tensor_dtype(tensor_name))
                print(f"Output shape [{tensor_name}]: {shape}, Size: {size}, Dtype: {dtype}")
                host_mem = cuda.pagelocked_empty(size, dtype)
                device_mem = cuda.mem_alloc(host_mem.nbytes)
                self.outputs.append(self.HostDeviceMem(host_mem, device_mem, dtype, shape))
                self.bindings.append(int(device_mem))

        # h_inputs = [buffer.host for buffer in self.inputs]
        d_inputs = [buffer.device for buffer in self.inputs]

        h_outputs = [buffer.host for buffer in self.outputs]
        d_outputs = [buffer.device for buffer in self.outputs]

        #Transfer input data from host to device
        for i, d_input in enumerate(d_inputs):
            '''
            pycuda.driver.memcpy_htod_async(dest, src, stream=None)
            Copy from the Python buffer src to the device poinster dest (an int or a DeviceAllocation)
            asynchronously, optionally serialized via stream. The size of the copy is determined by the size of
            the buffer.
            '''
            # cuda.memcpy_htod_async(d_input, model_inputs[i], self.stream)
            # for kernel execution time mearsurement, use synchronous copy --> So that the time.start() is executed only after the data is copied to the device
            print(f"Numpy array size (bytes): {model_inputs[i].itemsize * model_inputs[i].size}")
            cuda.memcpy_htod(d_input, model_inputs[i])
        
        bindings = self.bindings

        engine = self.engine
        for i in range(engine.num_io_tensors):
            self.context.set_tensor_address(engine.get_tensor_name(i), bindings[i])
        
        start = time.time()
        # Run inference
        self.context.execute_async_v3(stream_handle=self.stream.handle) # stream that allocated device memory
        
        # Synchronize the stream
        self.stream.synchronize()
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Elapsed time: {(end - start) * 1000:.0f}ms")

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="ONNX model exportation")
    parser.add_argument("--model", type=str, default='JambaMambaDecoderLayer-0-decoding.trt')
    parser.add_argument("--batch", type=int, default=64) # not used yet (TODO)
    parser.add_argument("--seqlen", type=int, default=256) # not used yet (TODO)
    parser.add_argument("--promptlen", type=int, default=128) # not used yet (TODO)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    engine_path = args.model #'JMlayer0/JambaMambaDecoderLayer-0-decoding.trt'
    model = TRTModel(engine_path)

    '''
    Tensor name: hidden_states
    Shape: (<dynamic>16, 1, 128)
    Dtype: <class 'numpy.float32'>
    Tensor name: conv_states
    Size: 16384
    Shape: (<dynamic>16, 256, 4)
    Dtype: <class 'numpy.float16'>
    Tensor name: ssm_states
    Size: 65536
    Shape: (<dynamic>16, 256, 16)
    '''
    model_inputs = []
    for i in range(model.engine.num_io_tensors):
        tensor_name = model.engine.get_tensor_name(i)
        if model.engine.get_tensor_mode(tensor_name) == trt.TensorIOMode.INPUT:
            shape = model.engine.get_tensor_profile_shape(name=tensor_name, profile_index=0)[2]
            assert args.batch <= shape[0], f"Batch size should be less than the maximum batch size ({shape[0]}) of the model"
            shape[0] = args.batch
            if tensor_name == "key_cache" or tensor_name == "value_cache":
                assert args.seqlen <= shape[2], f"Sequence length should be less than the maximum sequence length ({shape[2]}) of the model"
                shape[2] = args.seqlen
            elif tensor_name == "causal_mask":
                assert args.seqlen <= shape[3], f"Sequence length should be less than the maximum sequence length ({shape[3]}) of the model"
                shape[3] = args.seqlen

            dtype = trt.nptype(model.engine.get_tensor_dtype(tensor_name))
            
            random_input = np.random.randn(*shape).astype(dtype)
            if tensor_name == "causal_mask":
                random_input = np.triu(np.ones(shape=shape), k=0).astype(dtype)
            model_inputs += [np.ascontiguousarray(random_input).astype(dtype)]
    model(model_inputs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I tried to run and profile gpu for different batchsizes and sequence length for a layer within a Jamba model. When batchsize or sequence length is set to a large value, it gives "an illegal memory was encountered" error message. I want to run the tensorRT engine with batchsizes and sequence length that   I specified as a maximum value for the profile used to create the engine. (max_batch_size = 128 and max_seq_len = 8192 (dynamic axes) when I created the engine - Not included in the above code)
